# How to append an empty list in a for loop in Python and i got "None" when try to append the reversed string.Why its showing None?

Tags: python

```
string = "Hi how are you"
reversedString = []
mysplit = string.split(" ")
for i in mysplit:
    reverse = i[::-1]
    print reverse
    final_List =  reversedString.append(reverse)
print final_List
```

Result i am getting is:
iH
woh
era
uoy
None

Why i am getting "None" when try to append the reversed string.Please help

Comment: Because append doesn't return anything. Just do `reversedString.append(reverse)` and print `reversedString` in the end.

Comment: `final_List` is not needed here since  `reversedString` already has the list. `final_List` is  none because the return type of `append ` is none

Comment: Make a list comprehension like: ``res = ' '.join([i[::-1] for i in string.split()])`` that creates one complete string: ``'iH woh era uoy'``. But your problem was that you printed ``final_List`` which is just ``None`` because ``append`` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = "Hi how are you"
reversedString = []
mysplit = string.split(" ")

for i in mysplit:
    reverse = i[::-1]
    reversedString.append(reverse)

print  reversedString
```

output:

```
['iH', 'woh', 'era', 'uoy']
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.append(item)` modifies the `list` in place and returns `None`.

Just `print reversedString`:

```
string = "Hi how are you"
reversedString = []
mysplit = string.split(" ")
for i in mysplit:
    reverse = i[::-1]
    print reverse
    reversedString.append(reverse)
print reversedString
```

---

Also, `string.split(' ')` splits at *each* space character, so if you have `string = 'foo   bar'`, you'd get the list `['foo', '', '', 'bar']`; if you want to separate words with any amount of whitespace in between, just use `string.split()`.